How to conditionally apply `<HintPath>` elements in a `csproj` file?
So I recently discovered that when using msbuild with the /p:RestorePackagesPath flag, the <HintPath> tags inside of each csproj file seem to take precedence. see here.
Basically, when executing the following msbuild command:
MSBuild.exe "C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\SampleProject.sln" /p:RestorePackagesPath="C:\NuGetPackages"

msbuild will NOT look for my NuGet packages inside of the specified C:\NuGetPackages folder for <Reference>s with a <HintPath>. So if in my csproj file I have the following entry:
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

msbuild will look for the EntityFramework.6.3.0 NuGet entry in ..\packages\ folder and not my C:\NuGetPackages folder that I specify at the command line.
I thought I'd come up with a way to specify to ignore the <HintPath> entries conditionally, and be able to do so at the command line. For this I execute the following command:
MSBuild.exe "C:\ProgramData\SampleProject\SampleProject.sln" /p:RestorePackagesPath="C:\NuGetPackages" /p:RemoveHintPathsFlag=true

and to make this work, I include the following in my csproj file:
<!-- Define the RemoveHintPaths target that will be executed conditionally -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <RemoveHintPathsFlag>false</RemoveHintPathsFlag>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="RemoveHintPaths" BeforeTargets="ResolveReferences" Condition="'$(RemoveHintPathsFlag)' == 'true'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Set HintPath to an empty value for all references -->
    <Reference Include="@(Reference)">
      <HintPath></HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<!-- END OF RemoveHintPaths -->

Above, in the first part I tell the csproj file that the default value for RemoveHintPathsFlag is false, then I include a conditional <Target> that is to run BEFORE ResolveTargets (I also tried running AFTER ResolveTargets but that didn't work either) and is based on the value I provide in my msbuild command, in particular the /p:RemoveHintPathsFlag = true. This however does not work, the <HintPath> values are still all applied. Can anyone see why?
Also, as I can't get the above to work I thought I'd try the brute-force methodology adding conditions to the <HintPath>s as follows:
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
 <HintPath Condition="'$(RemoveHintPathsFlag)'=='false'">..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

and calling msbuild with /p:RemoveHintPathsFlag=true. To my surprise, this hasn't worked either.

Change <RemoveHintPathsFlag>false</RemoveHintPathsFlag> to <RemoveHintPathsFlag Condition="'$(RemoveHintPathsFlag)'==''">false</RemoveHintPathsFlag>, i.e. set RemoveHintPathsFlag to false when it is undefined. Or don't set a 'default' value at all.

One way to have condition based referenced in the project file is to have them in Choose. Example
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="SomeAssembly">
          <HintPath>..\..\bin-x86\SomeAssembly.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>true</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="SomeAssembly">
          <HintPath>..\..\bin-x64\SomeAssembly.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>true</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>


@Charlieface An ItemGroup element cannot contain a Choose element.
